# Can LLVM be used to produce optimized C-code

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

Is it possible to use LLVM to read in C code and make it faster? I've seen many discussions on using LLVM to transform C++ to (unreadable) C code but I'm wondering if LLVM can read in C code, and produce a file (code, not an executable) with the same functionality that is faster.

Comment: IIRC the LLVM tutorial does itself show some simple optimizations. So yes you can do them and then translate the IR into C source code.

Comment: Faster as measured by what method? C code doesn't have any inherent notion of speed.

Comment: Faster as in if I timed the original c-code's resulting executable it would take longer than the "translated/optimaized" LLVM c-code's executable. 

I will take a look the IIRC tutorial thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaComputing/llvm-cbe ... but it doesn't magically fix crappy code

Comment: You cannot time C code per se. You can only time C code compiled by a particular compiler. Note that timing unoptimised code is a total waste of time. In order to compare apples to apples you want to use the same compiler in both cases. So you measure code optimised via LLVM C-to-C transformation against code optimised by native LLVM methods. Now what kind of optimisation do you think will fare better, and why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

There is a C backend for LLVM, so you can compile C via LLVM IR to C and apply optimisation passes on the way, but what you are asking about is neither a design goal of that backend nor of LLVM as a whole. If it works in any particular case, then that is just a happy coincidence.

One of LLVM's goals is producing fast code using backends that resemble a variety of current hardware. C, however, does not even try to resemble a modern processor. Quite reasonably so, being fifty years older than the latest silicon miracles.

Answer (score -1):

LLVM is the compiler middle-end, it only understands LLVM-IR. To optimize C code you need a frontend which converts C to LLVM-IR. Clang does that. Essentially using clang to compile a C code, with optimizations enabled, invokes LLVM after the frontend is done converting the C code to LLVM-IR.

Here is a nice overview of how compiler works: https://cppdepend.com/blog/?p=321